# Queries in MS-Access:formatting a field in the middle of an sql UPDATE code

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, sql-update

I am having yet another problem with my data in ms-access.

Basically, what i'm doing is using multiple sql statements to pull, sort, and staight up change/manipulate data. The problem that im having currently is that i am trying to use a sql code like this:

```
UPDATE analyzedCopy2 SET analyzedCopy2.DateRange = #4/21/2009# to #4/29/2009#
```

but i can't figure out how to reformat DateRange (which is currently a date) to Text in the sql statement. I can't simply set the format manually because the sql code before this one is pulling in all of the data from another table and when that happens it changes the format of DateRange to date automattically since that is the type it is where it is coming from.

If anyone knows how to format a column with vba code then that would be fine too since i'm creating a vba code to run the queries in the order i want.

If anyone needs a better explanation of anything just let me know.

Comment: yahh...... I would still like to know how to do all i've asked above but i just re-ran my code and it didn't change the format of the column on me this time, no idea why by it didn't do it to me this time, im asuming i did something wrong the first time.

Comment: I don't understand your question. What data type is DateRange? And the "value" you're setting it to is nonsensical regardless of what data type DateRange is. Shows us the source data and format you want it to end up in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use SQL (DDL) to change some aspects of a table:

```
 ALTER TABLE TableName ALTER COLUMN  ColumnName Text(50)
```